# Some CSS Questions: Position & Margin

Tags: html, css, position, display

I am new here and to the world of web development. Hope someone clear a confusion I am having for sometime.

when specifying the container within a body, why do I see others put display: block, isn't that already the default for the display? Why the need to specify it in the CSS? Also, what is the difference between margin: 0 auto and margin: auto. I know that the 0 will do the top & bottom, and the auto, the left and right but will setting only auto do all sides?

Thank you

Comment: when I say the default, I mean the default for a div.

Comment: you can easily find your answer with a simply google search ...

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` is setting margin-top/bottom to 0, and margin-left/right to auto.

Comment: It's like `margin: y x`

Comment: @TemaniAfif I know that display: block creates a block level element but I don't see why it's needed for a div, I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: it's never need for a div ... but maybe you have other style overriding it so you added it agian to be sure it's block

Comment: when writing CSS we don't leave things to hazard .. you want something to be block so you specifiy it even if it's the default behavior ... don't rely on default unless you are sure there is nothing else that will change this

Comment: @TemaniAfif fair enough, I have been following tutorials and I kept seeing this come up but now I guess I see the point of not relying on the default. thanks.